# Web-based Gmail displays consecutive white space but does not print it

Tags: html, printing, gmail, whitespace

Through a .NET application I am generating an HTML email. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="TX26_HTM 26.0.630.500" name="GENERATOR">
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12pt;text-align:left;">
<p lang="en-US" style="text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:'Courier New';font-size:10pt;color:#008000;white-space:pre">  AA1887¬ DFWPHX  715A  900A 757   0/ 0/ 0   0/ 0/12   0/ 0/ 0   47/ 47/176   0/ 0/ 0/ 7  R/F</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The email is required to have a fixed width font and consecutive white space is to be preserved as it is important for readability. When I send this email to Gmail and view it in a browser it looks like it's supposed to:

[image]

Now when i click on the Print button it renders a printable version. It seems to preserve the color but not the consecutive white space:

[image]

I have tried variations of the white-space tag without any difference in the print version. So my question...is there a tag that Gmail uses that would preserve the consecutive white space while in the Print rendering?

Comment: When you say _I have tried variations of the white-space tag without any difference in the print version._ does this meant you've tried something to the effect of: `AA1887¬&nbsp;&nbsp;DFWPHX&nbsp;&nbsp;715&nbsp;&nbsp;900A&nbsp;&nbsp;757&nbsp;&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0/12&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;47/&nbsp;47/176&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0/&nbsp;0/&nbsp;7&nbsp;R/F` whereby you're replacing a space with `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried replacing all spaces with the [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) `\u00A0` ?

Comment: By white space tag I mean the white-space:pre tag. let me try the NBSP and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @EGC. Since I am using the HTML Agility Pack I implemented a quick and dirty function. From what I read it's not a good idea to use InnerHtml to replace the inner text. However for my purposes the output is strictly defined.

```
'get all the <p> nodes
Dim xpP As String = "//p"
Dim pNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpP)
If pNodes IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each pNode As HtmlNode In pNodes
        'replace inner text white space with NBSP
        pNode.InnerHtml = pNode.InnerText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
    Next pNode
End If
```